# PostgreSQL How to put constraint on column of type arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, constraints

I have two tables in Postgresql.

`table_1` contains sources

```
Sources
A_src 
B_src
C_src
```

`table_2` is as follows

```
Result;Result_sources
2.3; {A_src;C_src}
43; {B_src;C_src}
11; {A_src;B_src;C_src}
```

How can I write a constraint on `table_2.Result_sources` which enables its array entries to only come from `table_1.Sources` column

Comment: I think you need trigger for it, you cant use check(other table) or FK constraints (different data types)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, and a trigger is no substitute since you cannot avoid race conditions unless you use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions.

This problem begs for normalization: create a table that implements and m-to-n relationship between `table_1` and `table_2`.